# Can I use 'ember generate' to generate tests for existing 'objects'?

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember EAK project migrated to Ember CLI, with tests coded for mocha/chai test runner which don't run correctly in the migrated project, even though I've installed ember-cli-mocha. Can I use 'ember generate', with the mocha blueprints, to generate new test stubs where I can then go in and more or less re-implement what I had with the tests in EAK?

So I want to use 'ember generate' to generate tests for existing routes, controllers & views, rather than generating new stub objects and tests together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed do this, using the `ember generate` blueprints of `controller-test`, `route-test`, etc.

```
ember generate controller-test my-resource
```

This is documented at http://www.ember-cli.com/#appendix. This is an ember-cli feature, not an ember feature, so is covered in the documentation for the former. Additional information can be obtained with `ember generate help`.

Comment: If there's a doc on ember generate, I can't find it. The 'testing' sections don't cover it. 'generated objects' doesn't cover it (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/generated-objects/). 'testing controllers' doesn't cover it (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/testing-controllers/). But I can do some trial and error and maybe figure out the CLI syntax by sticking '-test' at the end to see if I can create a test stub for a particular 'object'. thx

Comment: Is there anything that generates stuff more than stubs?

Comment: I can't find the doc either

Answer (score 6):

Try the following

`ember g component-test component-module-name
ember g component-test component-module-name --unit`

`ember g component-test --help`

Shows

```
ember generate <blueprint> <options...>
  Generates new code from blueprints.
  aliases: g
  --dry-run (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -d
  --verbose (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -v
  --pod (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -p
  --classic (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -c
  --dummy (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -dum, -id
  --in-repo-addon (String) (Default: null)
    aliases: --in-repo <value>, -ir <value>

      component-test <name> <options...>
        Generates a component integration or unit test.
        --test-type (integration, unit) (Default: integration)
          aliases: -i (--test-type=integration), -u (--test-type=unit), --integration (--test-type=integration), -unit (--test-type=unit)
```